# Cypress - how to logout from site

Tags: javascript, testing, automation, automated-tests, cypress

Is in Cypress any possibility to log out from page if you are logged in? Or to check if I'm logged?

My problem is that if I'm running tests by one in browser then Cypress always need to log in. But if I start it from cmd it only needs to log in on the first test but at the next one you are already logged in.

```
// Visit the site
cy.visit(
  "https://zeteodemo.uat.creasoft.cz/login?ReturnUrl=%2fVehicleInsuranceV2%2fCompare%3fOsobniCislo1%3d1%26ProductsFilter%3dAXA-ONLINE"
);

// Enter username
cy.get(".login__username")
  .type("tester")
  .should("have.value", "tester");

// Enter password
cy.get(".login__password")
  .type("1")
  .should("have.value", "1");

// Click the login button
cy.get(".button-login").click();
```

Comment: I might be completely off here and pretty interested in what answers you'll get. But have you considered using cookies (https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/cookies.html#Syntax)? Cypress deletes cookies after each test but you could preserve a cookie of logged in user a based on its value decide if you need to click the login button. It's just an idea though, never done that before..

Comment: Yeah, I was trying cookies but it doesn't work. Maybe I don't get it right and I was using them wrong so I'm asking.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've got Cypress tests running for several environments, one of those has issues with the login state. Deleting cookies helps sometimes, but not always. So to keep the tests stable I decided to create an if statement (what in itself isn't a best practice) to go to the known application state as fast as possible.

What I do is using the custom command below in every `beforeEach()` that could use a login:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('login', function () {
    cy.get('body').then($body => {
        if ($body.find('.user-profile-name').length === 1) {
            cy.log('Already logged in')
        } else {
            cy.get('.login-button').click()
        }
    })
})
```

What is does is checking if the browser is already logged in, since `.user-profile-name` should exist. If it does not exist the browser isn't logged in, so Cypress needs to click the `.login-button` button.

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much!

Comment: Thank you very much, this solved my problem as well.